# Compute the integral $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{e^{ix}}e^{-ikx}\text{d}x $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I was told to compute the following integral
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{e^{ix}}e^{-ikx}\text{d}x
$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to start. Should I expand the exponentials in terms of trigonometric functions or what is the trick here? Can I use theory about Fourier series to simplify this? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Were you told whether or not you'd get an exact answer?

Comment: Do you know enough complex analysis to know the [Cauchy Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)?

Comment: I was told to compute the precise value of that integral for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so I guess there is an exact answer.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I know that formula, but this is an exercise in Fourier analysis course.

Answer (score 3):

Write 
$$e^{e^{ix}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{nix}}{n!}$$
and use the fact that 
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{nix} \, dx=
\begin{cases}2\pi & n = 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Am I allowed to change the order of summation and integration? If that is true, I get $\frac{2\pi}{k!}$ as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what theorems you know at the moment, but hopefully you have some way to justify interchanges, as it would be difficult to do Fourier analysis without one! I personally would probably use the [bounded convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Also, beware of negative $k$ in your answer...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $z=e^{ix}$. The integral becomes a contour integral along the unit circle, so Cauchy integral formula applies.

Answer (score 1):

Put

$$z:=e^{ix}\;,\;\;-\pi\le x\le \pi\implies dz=iz\,dx\,,\,\,|z|=1\implies dx=-\frac izdz\implies$$

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{e^{ix}}e^{ikx}\,dx=\oint_C e^zz^k\left(-\frac iz\,dz\right)=\frac1i\oint_Ce^zz^{k-1}dz=
\begin{cases}0,&k\ge1\\{}\\
\cfrac{2\pi}{(-k)!},&k<1\end{cases}$$

With $\;C=\;$ the unit circle. Use [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)